# Where I can buy an original OS X Leopard PPC disc for my iMac G4?

Tags: macos, imac, install, leopard, powerpc

I've a wonderful iMac G4 with 2 GB of RAM so I can install/upgrade from Panther to Leopard  but I cannot officially buy from Apple site!

Is there a possibility somewhere to buy an original disk?

Comment: Have you tried eBay?

Comment: You might be able to buy it from Apple.  I bought a two-versions-old OS from an Apple retail store.  They just don't keep them in stock, so you'll have to order it and then come back in a week to pick it up.

Answer (score 3):

Besides maybe posting to Craigslist for a better deal, 10.5.6 is still available for sale on Amazon.

Please know there was no PPC-specific version of the installer (it works cross-architecture), so if you find one it will work on that Mac (as long as its processor is 867 Mhz or faster w/ 9 GB of free disk space and a DVD drive). It was only Tiger that had separate installers.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to get Leopard is to find someone who had Leopard who then upgraded to Snow Leopard.

Because Apple doesn't sell "upgrades" as such (only full system versions), they can legally and legitimately give or sell you their Leopard disk.

Answer (score 0):

One can usually find old versions of Mac OS on [eBay](http://www.ebay.com).

Answer (score 0):

I have [seen it suggested](http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=12487005) that you can order via Apple’s phone sales line ([+1-800-MY-APPLE](http://www.apple.com/contact/)). This may be a good option if you can not find it for less than original retail (US$129) through third-party retailers, auctions, or classified listings.